# Setting Up Google Analytics Data Stream for Electron Desktop App

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, electron, analytics

I'm interested in using a library such as the one below for analytics in an Electron app that I'm working on.

https://github.com/hajeonghun/electron-google-analytics4

My question arises when setting up a property on Google Analytics.  From what I understand you need to set up a data stream in order to get a Google Analytics tracking ID.

How should I go about setting up a data stream for my Electron desktop app?

None of the options (website, Android, iOS) seem to apply to my case but it seems possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just treat it as a website for simplicity.

It's up to you how you track website-related things in your app. Maybe you don't exactly have the concept of a pageview, but really an electron app is not much different from a typical SPA site, just served in a browser with cut/hidden functionality.